# How fast can zlib be on a slow pc?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I have a 500Mhz CPU and 256MB RAM machine running 32bit Linux.

I have a large number of files around 300KB in size. I need to compress them very fast. I have set up the compression level for zlib at Z_BEST_SPEED. Is there any other measure I could take?

Is it possible to compress 25-30 files like this in a second on such a machine?

Comment: The worst bottleneck with so many files would be your HDD. Put a SSD into the machine to avoid it.

Comment: @Carl Norum I am about to try it but I am first just asking theoretically as I will have to install zlib there so maybe it would be slow anyways.

Comment: I don't know Richard, is it possible?  You're the one with the hardware -- you tell us.

Comment: @JustSid So many files - "25-30". Seriously? That's not many files...

Comment: Use a different compression library?   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124239/fastest-c-file-compression-library-available

Comment: @chibacity, that was 25-30 files **per second**, not total.

Comment: @Mark Ransom And that would be a maximum read speed of less than 7.5-9MB per second. Does that justify recommending getting an SSD as a general solution to the problem. I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially talking about a 10MB/sec speed. Even if you were to only copy the files from one place to another I would doubt that your slow hardware could do it. So, for compression I would vote **No** - it's not possible "to compress 25-30 files like this in **a second** on such a machine".

Comment: What if I first load all files into memory and then start compressing? Would that help or would it still be too slow?

Comment: @Richard Knop - The whole process together cannot be faster than simply copying the files. If you place them in RAM to speed things up (do you have enough RAM?) then in will be this operation that will be the slow part.

Comment: @Vilx, yes he has enough RAM. Depending on his Linux flavor it's possible to have a small memory footprint that will leave 10MB for in-memory data. However, transferring these files from disk to RAM also takes time... Is it included in the 1 second @Richard is aiming for?

Comment: @Android Eve I could load the files to memory before the program where I need fast compression starts.

Comment: @Richard: well then why not load them into memory *and compress them* before the critical part of the program? If you're making a minor modification to the data just before compression, perhaps there's a better way to compress than zlib.

Comment: @Vilx: in theory it could be faster for certain data: if the files compress well then writing the compressed data might be significantly faster than jut copying (i.e. writing uncompressed). If the data doesn't compress well, then the questioner is wasting his time ;-)